# In Flutter bottom navigation bar should disappear when we navigate to new screen

Tags: dart, flutter

Hi all assume there are three pages A,B,c in bottom navigation bar and there is a button in A when pressed it navigate to screen D Im still able to see bottom navigation bar here please help me to solve this
P

Comment: Depends on how you navigate to screen d, are you using `Navigator.of(context).push` ???

Comment: Yes bro whatever page I navigate to I cannot escape from that bar

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen(reference:name,refKey:uKey,userId: _userID,)),
                     );

Comment: Does your homescreen also contain a botton nav bar?

Comment: Yes HomeScreen also has Bottom navigation bar

Comment: That's why you see the Bottom nav there. Remove it from there.

Comment: no no i mean for homescreen() class i didn't define bottom navigation bar but still it is appearing on homescreen(). We have a queue()  class (i have written bottom navigation bar), from which we navigate to HomeScreen(). I dont want bottom navigation bar to continue with navigator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your screen D as StatefulWidget.
For example:

```
class ScreenD extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new ScreenDState();
}

class ScreenDState extends State<ScreenD> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold();
  }
}
```

Mark your screen A as StatefulWidget too same with screen D.
Then a button in screen A onPressed handler housed in BottomNavigationBar:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenD()),);
```

It should remove the BottomNavigationBar when screen D renders.

Answer (score 11):

i had the same problem and i found that `rootNavigator:true` solve it

```
Navigator.of(context,rootNavigator: true).push(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @Skander answer, using RootNavigator on the "of" method should do the trick.

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(...);
```

Here is the description of rootNavigator option, according to documentation:

> If rootNavigator is set to true, the state from the furthest instance of this class is given instead. Useful for pushing contents above all subsequent instances of Navigator.